# Chofetz Chaim Tefillin Minhag

Tags: minhag, tefilin, chofetz-chaim

Do we know the Chofetz Chaim's minhag with respect to Tefillin (i.e., how did he wrap the Tefillin around his arm and hand)?  Or if there was a minhag generally in the Radun Yeshiva?

Comment: There is a type of kesher shel yad named after him that some people advocate, but I don't know if he actually used such a knot or came up with it. (I tried to find a photo of the knot, but I couldn't find one.)

Comment: There is a (somewhat) [famous photo](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/Israel_Meir_Poupko%2C_tefillin.jpg) of the Chofetz Chaim wearing tefillin, though his hand and bicep are hidden from view.

Comment: Thank you!  I wonder if his son in law took to his minhag (probably not?).

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: @ezra Ira know... the book [and head, including tefilin] in the “photo” look to me like a drawing.